# singular nouns that are plural in form

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Could you come up with as many singular nouns that are plural in form as possible?
Examples include "a woods" and "a golf links." I don't want names of diseases and fields of study.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Once you have them, what will you do with them?

Comment: They have pedagogical significance.

Comment: "The woods" perhaps, but hardly ever "a woods",  and it usually takes a plural verb.

Comment: *"The woods **are** lovely, dark, and deep."* (Robert Frost)

Comment: @JamesK "A thick woods runs along the boundary of the estate." http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/wood

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment or similar?

Comment: Whatever the dictionary may say, _a thick woods_ is not standard English. It should be _a wood_ or _an area of woodland_.

Comment: @KateBunting Are you British?

Comment: Yes. Would _a woods_ be acceptable in other Englishes?

Comment: The dictionary I quoted is Merriam-Webster, an American dictionary.

Comment: You have to ask a specific question. We can objectively come up with a single (or small number) of words based on some criteria, but asking for *as many words as possible* is off topic.

Comment: The only reason that *a thick woods* works at all (and it's highly unidiomatic anyway) is because it includes an adjective. *A woods runs along* would not be acceptable in any way. Dictionaries also make mistakes. Their example sentences are often not well curated. I myself have written to Merriam-Webster to have them move an example sentence into a different grammatical classification because their process had got it wrong. The editor who wrote back to me told me that they are grateful to readers who help them correct some of their examples.

Comment: @JasonBassford Maybe you don't speak US English. Here's an example of "a woods" without an adjective: We had a woods exactly like the one Robert Frost describes above in his poem, “Stopping by Woods on a Snowy Evening.” https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=o_9lmkGcx3EC&pg=PA113&dq=%22a+woods%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij-Prvj8LpAhVCCqYKHbj4DBk4HhDoAQg9MAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20woods%22&f=false

Comment: @Apollyon Robert Frost wrote poetry. Poetry follows different rules and conventions. Many things that are unacceptable in regular text are quite acceptable in poetry.

Comment: @JasonBassford The sentence, "We had a woods exactly like the one Robert Frost describes above in his poem . . .," is not by Robert Frost, but by Gladys Hunt and ‎Barbara Hampton. You could also find "a woods" in the documents of the US department of agriculture.

Answer (score 1):

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston et al. (2002) on pp.345–48 (section titled "Singular nouns with the *·s* ending") has the following nouns and explanations:

> #### Diseases and ailments
>
> [1] *bends hives mumps rabies rickets shingles*
>   [2] *haemorrhoids hiccups measles*
>
> [...] *Hiccups* can also denote the condition where one is producing such spasms, and in this case it can be construed as singular or plural for purposes of subject–verb agreement: *Hiccups is/are unpleasant, I concede, but it/they are hardly life-threatening*. *Hiccups* is thus best treated as a plural noun, with the NP it heads optionally recategorised as singular by virtue of being interpreted as denoting a condition rather than the spasms themselves [...]. The same applies to *haemorrhoids*. And probably also to *measles*, except that here the use of *measle* and *measles* for the spots that characterise the disease is relatively uncommon; many speakers will have only the form *measles* denoting the disease and for them it is likely to belong with the singular nouns in [1].

---

> #### Nouns with the *·s* ending in both singular and plural
>
> [3] *barracks crossroads gallows headquarters innings kennels
>   links means mews rapids waterworks*
>
> [...] *Innings* is used in connection with such games as cricket: for baseball the term is *inning*, with *innings* a regular plural. *Kennels* here denotes an establishment where dogs are bred or looked after while their owners are away; *kennels* can also be the ordinary plural of *kennel*, “small hut for a dog”. [...] BrE *licensed premises* (“pub”) belongs here too, and so for many people does *splits* as used in gymnastics, etc.: *a licensed premises*, *a finely executed splits*. *Series* and *species* might also be included, though it is doubtful if these are perceived as containing a morphological ending *·s* at all.

---

> #### Nouns in *·ics*
>
> [4] *acoustics classics economics ethics linguistics mathematics
>   mechanics phonetics physics politics semantics statistics*
>   [5] *athletics gymnastics*
>
> The nouns in [4] denote fields of study (with some having other meanings too); those in [5] various sporting activities. For some of them there is a related singular noun without the *·s* (*acoustic*, *classic*, *ethic*, *statistic*), and these have regular count plurals [...].

---

> #### Games
>
> [6] *billiards checkers*<sup>AmE</sup> *draughts*<sup>BrE</sup> *fives ninepins*
>   [7] *cards darts dominoes skittles*
>
> As names of games these normally take singular agreement, but those in [7] can also be ordinary plurals applied to the entities used in the game [...]. The natural solution for [7] is to say that these are plural nouns, with the NP they head being recategorised as singular when interpreted as denoting the game (a singular concept) rather than the pieces. But the nouns in [6] apply only to the game (ignoring irrelevant senses), and are therefore better treated as simply singular nouns, with the *·s* part of the lexical base.<sub><sup>For some speakers *draughts* belongs in [7], being applicable to the pieces as well as the game. The coordination *cowboys and indians* also belongs in [7], but with the singular forms denoting participants.</sup></sub>

The book also talks about the word *news* as an isolated example, and mentions *shambles* elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Some singular nouns that are plural in form are :-**
**news, gallows, summons, shambles.**

1. *This news is not true.*
2. *A gallows was fixed.*
3. *A summons was issued.*
4. *The house was a shambles.*

Comment: summons is just a noun ending in s, it's not in a plural form.

Comment: Look, these are all **singular nouns** : Mathematics, Physics, Measles, Mumps, News, Gallows, etc.

Comment: That is correct, you could [edit]. But unlike those, "summons" is not a noun in a plural form that is being used as a singular noun.  It is just a noun that happens to end in the letter "s".  Moreover "Mathematics", for example, is singular and non-count (usually) So you don't say "a mathematics". The OP hasn't been quite clear, but it seems they want "not subjects or diseases" and they want countable nouns (like "A golf links")  So "a gallows" and "a shambles" would seem to be good examples of what the OP wants...

Comment: **News** is plural in form but singular in use. Similarly,, *gallows, summons, barracks etc.* are plural in form (i.e., they seem to be plural because of their **-s** ending); but they are singular in use.

Comment: "Summons" has the plural form "summonses", so JK is right when he says that the "s" on  "summons" is not a plural suffix.